# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + EJB on Wildfly 10

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, wildfly, ejb-3.1

I'm developing a Web application using JavaEE stack (Hibernate + EJB3 + PrimeFaces) but for DAOs, I'm planing to use Spring Data JPA.

To get started I have, some questions:

1) Is it possible to use ONLY spring-data-jpa?

2) How do I load applicationContext.xml?

What I tried until now:

1) Created /META-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">
        <!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
        <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

        <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="java:jboss/datasources/PGDB" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            <!-- Set JPA properties -->
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.test.*</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <!-- Set share cache mode -->
            <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
            <!-- Set validation mode -->
            <property name="validationMode" value="NONE" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the repository 
            interfaces -->
        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.*" />
    </beans>
```

2) Created beans.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd" >
            </beans>
```

3) Created CdiConfig.java:

```
            import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
            import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
            import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
            import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

            public class CdiConfig {
                @Produces
                @Dependent
                @PersistenceContext
                public EntityManager entityManager;
            }
```

4) Added to web.xml the following:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

5) Implemented a repository:

```
    import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    import com.test.MessageBundle;

    @Default
    public interface MessageBundleRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageBundle, String> {


    }
```

6) This is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WPR_MESSAGE_BUNDLE")
public class MessageBundle implements BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 64)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE", length = 1024)
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "LOCALE", length = 16)
    private String locale;

    @Column(name = "ACTION", length = 255)
    private String action;

    //GETS and SETS
}
```

7) Stateless Session Bean

```
@Stateless
public class MessageBundleService {
    @Inject private MessageBundleRepository repMsgBundle;

    public MessageBundleService() {

    }

    public MessageBundle save(MessageBundle mb) {
        return repMsgBundle.save(mb);
        //return null;
    }
}
```

I believe CDI part is working properly because MessageBundleRepository is being injected to MessageBundleService but I believe Spring Context is not being loaded on startup because if I add invalid string in applicationContext.xml, nothing happens and I see in log file that default persistence context is being loaded instead of what I configured in applicationContext.xml. Take a look at this log:

```
    23:59:45,892 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    23:59:45,895 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
    23:59:45,958 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Envers integration enabled? : true
    23:59:46,348 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Event] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
```

Please note my applicationContext.xml configuration is for SQL Server but this logs suggests configuration is being done to H2.

What am I missing? Please keep in mind I don't want to use whole Spring MVC or Spring Boot. Is it possible to use just spring-data-jpa + Hibernate?

The reason I decided to use spring-data-jpa is the feature that allows to scan entities on classpath instead of inform them in configuration file. I need something dynamic because it's a modular application.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (18/06/2017):**
If I delete beans.xml and CdiConfig.java, Spring seems to work, my entity is found and table is created but I cannot inject MessageBundleRepository (#5) in my session bean MessageBundleService (#7).

Now I suppose there is something wrong on CDI. Probably, EntityManager is being created after JpaRepository framework causing injection failure. Please see following log:

```
        javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:118)
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:94)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```